# Updating a table with row number in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, row-number

Trying to update a table with a unique iD column as there is no unique key column in the same.

When using the below CTE, I am getting an error of relation does not exist for the CTE name in the update statement. but the same is working fine when select statement is executed.

Query used:

```
With updateid As
(
SELECT 
ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Model DESC) AS RN
FROM aud
)UPDATE updateid SET ID='AUD'||repeat('0',5-length(cast(RN as varchar)))||cast(RN as varchar)
```

Error encountered:

> ```
> ERROR:  relation "updateid" does not exist
> LINE 7: )UPDATE updateid SET ID='AUD'+replicate('0',5-len(cast(RN as...
>                 ^
> SQL state: 42P01
> Character: 95
> ```

The select statement that worked well:

```
With updateid As
(
SELECT 
ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Model DESC) AS RN
FROM aud
)Select * from updateid
```

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` - the `+` is for adding numbers. There also is no `replicate()` function in Postgres. And you can't update the result of a CTE in Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to update the table from some source result set, you can use [`update ... from ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-update.html) with join condition specified in `where` clause:

> ```
> create table t
> as
> select q, null::int as w
> from unnest(array[1,2,3]) as q
> ```

> ```
> with s as (
>   select row_number() over(order by q desc) as rn
>     , ctid as row_id
>   from t
> )
> update t
> set w = rn
> from s
> where t.ctid = s.row_id
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
>  q |  w
> -: | -:
>  3 |  1
>  2 |  2
>  1 |  3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fc1d9647ac2ff111166c07ad5d59135f)*

Comment: Thank you, the sample query worked well for me..... the update ran as expected. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sequence for this:

```
create sequence temp_sequence_x;

update t
    set id = nextval('temp_sequence_x');

drop sequence temp_sequence_x;
```

I don't recommend making the primary key a string, as your code suggests that you want to do.  But you can, of course, put that logic into the `set` clause if needed.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=64fafddc8698977c3d76e6f6691f557d) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  If there are a group of keys that are unique, then there are alternative methods.  However, your question does not provide that information.  And, the sequence approach is pretty simple.

Comment: Thank you so much....... for showing a new approach for the query.